# SVN export files changed since date or revision (Windows svn.exe)

Tags: windows, svn

I have a repository of sql scripts, some of which change for each of our monthly releases (different scripts change each month).

I am trying to automate the compilation of deployment packages and want to be able to export all the scripts which have changed since the last release, which has a known date and known revision.

SVN Branches are per release, SVN Tags are per build.

I have googled and know that `svn diff --summarize -r {2012-05-01} svn://server/path/to/ > files.txt` gives me a list of all the changes but how do I then use that list to export only those files using Windows CMD - all the examples I have found are for Linux and use Linux commands.

Is there any other direct way of doing this in SVN? (using SVN Export?)

Comment: Hey Finn! I'm sick, tell me a story!

Answer (score 1):

1. Use revision number as start revision, not date: it's more bullet-proof
2. Use revision range, even if end revision is HEAD: it's more bullet-proof

   - You can have Bash even on Windows, and use Bash-scripts
   - You can install Ruby and use Ruby script (or compile Ruby to exe)

At last

- You can install TortoiseSVN and prepare tree in GUI by hand

or

- Write own parser of diff output (PoserShell will do it)

`>svn diff --summarize -r 26:34 http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/`

`A       http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Dr%C3%A6p%C3%A6r.ma%C3%BEar.sv%C3%A6nskan.man.eller.smalensk%C3%A6n.txt`

`M       http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.en.txt`

`M       http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.fr.txt`

`M       http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.de.txt`

`M      http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk`

(copy all files, which have A|M in fist char of line, or pre-grep all strings, which have trailing slash after path-base /filter last string in my example/)